# drawing a number line in wp8 app

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to draw a number line in wp8 app but unable to do so
I want to create a line and show numbers on it. Then I would like to have a pointer on it pointing on a number on number line.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

I can point you in the approximate direction.

use a canvas and when drawing a line use Line. A line is s line with no pointers. You can places textblocks nearby.

you then add line, textblocks etc to canvasvas children.